# Recommendation letters: The more the better?

Tags: recommendation-letter

***Is*** there any upper limit for the number of recommendation letters for an application?

***Does*** the strength of an application get enhanced by containing more recommendation letters?

***What*** if the additional letters are coming from less-related (to the field that one is applying for) staff, but impressive enough? For example suppose one is going to apply for Physics and 2 recommendation letters are required. He gets two letters from physics professor and besides he is sure he can get a good letter from a math professor. What should he do?

Thanks.

PS: The target is a Grad school.

Comment: Yes there's an upper limit: Whatever the number of letters the announcement asks for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many recommendation letters are enough?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12508/how-many-recommendation-letters-are-enough)

Comment: Apply for what?  College?  Grad School?  Postdoc?  Tenure Track?  The answers are very different.  I guess you mean grad school?

Comment: Vote to close as "Unclear what you're asking" because the OP did not specify the use of the recommendation letters.

Comment: In practice, I would set the upper limit as the number they ask for, plus one.  As others have remarked, you don't want to overwhelm the people reading your application.  //  Yes, it is helpful to include a strong recommendation from a math professor when writing a physics application.

Comment: @Noah: Well, indeed it's a Grad school.

Answer (score 1):

**Does the strength of an application get enhanced by containing more recommendation letters?**

Not necessarily. Having too many recommendation letters can overwhelm the person reviewing your application and it may leave a bad impression of you in a couple of ways. One example is you do not know if the the reviewer will go through all of the letters that you provided. This may lead to the reviewer not being able to have a clear picture of who you are, what is your work ethic and how driven you are (these are just some general examples of what a reviewer could be looking for). Generally, most applications ask for 2-3 letters of recommendation.

**What if the additional letters are coming from less-related (to the field that one is applying for) staff, but impressive enough?**

If it doesn't specify what kind of letter you need to submit, the letters of recommendation that you think will help the application the most is the ones you should send. If you are still unsure, you can call them and ask how many letters of recommendation people usually send them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd place a limit at around three. To add too many might come through as bragging about the people you know, or trying to add weight by collecting all fluff you can get your hands on. Make sure you get strong letters from people who really know your work.